# discompose javascript react state with three dots, but why we are specifying state and state's attribute separately

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner in react, and javascript in general. And rencently I been following a Youtube tutorial. In the tutorial, I saw the folling code:

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    console.log(action)
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TO_BASKET':
            // keep the state to be whatever it is, 
            // and the basket is whatever it currently is plus the item passed inside.
            return {
                ...state,
                basket: [...state.basket, action.item],
            };

        case 'REMOVE_FROM_BASKET':
            const index = state.basket.findIndex(
                (basketItem) => basketItem.id === action.id
            );
            let newBasket = [...state.basket];

            if (index >= 0) {
                newBasket.splice(index, 1);
            } else {
                console.warn(
                    `Cant remove product (id: ${action.id}) as its not in the basket!`
                )
            }

            return {
                ...state,
                basket: newBasket
            }

        default:
            return state;
    }
```

I think I understand what the code is doing at a high level, such that this specifies how the reducer function is handling different requests based on the action's type.

The part that I am confusing is, from what I understand, the basket is one attribute of the state,
then why in the line

```
return {
                ...state,
                basket: newBasket
            }
```

it's returning the basket alongside with the state, why couldn't it be something like

return {
state.basket : newBasket }

Thanks for reading my question this far, much appreciate.

Comment: One reason: `return { state.basket : newBasket }` is invalid syntax, so it couldn't be used... did you mean to ask why it's not `return { basket : newBasket }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax in question is returning a shallow clone of the entire `state` object, and overriding `state.basket` with a value of `newBasket`.

```js
return {
  ...state,
  basket: newBasket
}
```

For example:

```js
const state = {
  basket: [],
  total: 0,
  user: null,
};

const stateClone = {
  ...state,
  basket: ['apple']
};
```

`stateClone` is now `{ basket: ['apple'], total: 0, user: null }` - AND it's a new object in memory.

The clone is necessary in order for the reducer to work properly, since reducers depend on immutable state. The mutable way to update `state.basket` would be:

```js
state.basket = newBasket;
return state;
```

However this mutates the original `state` object, updating the reference in memory rather than creating a copy. This will cause the reducer to work incorrectly (e.g. it won't detect that the state has changed).

Here are the MDN docs on the spread operator when cloning an object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals

Comment: Thank you Joe, you really helped me with understanding this topic. Appreciate you!